# Docker Redis TLS authentication failure with .netcore app

Tags: docker, ssl, .net-core, redis

I am trying to use redis with tls with a netcore application and I get an authentication error

### **The Setup:**

#### Docker:

I created a redis docker container using redis:6.2.0

docker-compose.yaml:

```
.
.
redis:
    image: redis:6.2.0
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --appendonly yes
    container_name: "cxm-redis"
    ports:
     - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - cxm-redis-data:/data
      - C:/SaaS/certs/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - C:/SaaS/certs/tests/tls/redis.crt:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.crt
      - C:/SaaS/certs/tests/tls/redis.key:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.key
      - C:/SaaS/certs/tests/tls/ca.crt:/usr/local/etc/redis/ca.crt
```

up to here all looks good, (as far as I can tell) I managed to authenticate using the following command
`redis-cli --tls --cert ../usr/local/etc/redis/redis.crt --key /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.key --cacert /usr/local/etc/redis/ca.crt` and I can succesfully ping and request keys.

I created the certificates with openssl and for the redis.conf i am using the [redis.conf example from redis](https://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf)

The important bits:

```
### TLS
tls-port 6379
tls-cert-file /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.crt
tls-key-file /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.key
tls-ca-cert-file /usr/local/etc/redis/ca.crt
```

#### netcore:

For my .netcore application I am using the StackExchange library and for the TLS connection I followed the [instructions here](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_csharp/#using-ssl-and-stackexchangeredis), like so

```
var options = new ConfigurationOptions
{
    EndPoints = { "redis-test:6379" },
    Password = "not-the-actual-password",
    Ssl = true
};
options.CertificateSelection += delegate {
    return new X509Certificate2("./redis_certificate.p12");
};
_db = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options).GetDatabase();
```

the redis_certificate.p12 was generated using openssl with this command line
`openssl pkcs12 -export -out sample_certificate.p12 -inkey redis.key -in redis.crt`

### The Issue:

When I make a request to redis from my app I get the following error:

**It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). There was an authentication failure; check that passwords (or client certificates) are configured correctly. AuthenticationFailure on redis-test:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted**
in my apps logs, and I get the following in my redis logs:

- **Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number**
- **Error accepting a client connection: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca,**
- **Error accepting a client connection: (null)**

Are there any apparent mistakes in my setup I am failing to see? This is my first time trying this and maybe I am assuming too much or heading down the wrong way..

Trying to resolve this I found several questions with a similar issue but implementing their fixes did not resolve my issue..

### a few of the things I tried

- sending different ssl protocols from my .netcore app
- sending the pfx/p12 certificate in different ways
- several different redis configurations

Edit: I can provide as much code as needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one facing the same issue, it seems the server was using a non routed CA for the server certificates, the solution I found was to use the CertificateValidation callback of StackExchange.Redis library with the following code

```
private static bool CheckServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
   X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if ((sslPolicyErrors & SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
    {
        // check that the untrusted ca is in the chain
        var ca = new X509Certificate2(_redisSettings.CertificatePath);
        var caFound = chain.ChainElements
            .Cast<X509ChainElement>()
            .Any(x => x.Certificate.Thumbprint == ca.Thumbprint);

        return caFound;
    }
    return false;
}
```

also an important part of the code being the condition

```
if((sslPolicyErrors & SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
```